# How do I get an event to keep triggering while hover?

Tags: jquery

Okay so here's my small snippet of code:

```
base.$el.delegate('.mb-panel', 'hover', base.hover = function(){
    base.change( base.$panels.index($(this)) + base.adj );          
});
```

Basically I want `base.change( base.$panels.index($(this)) + base.adj );` to keep executing as long as the user hovers over `.mb-panel`. So right now that event is firing once on `mouseenter()` and once on `mouseleave()` because I'm using `hover()`.

I've tried adding `base.hover();` to make it a sort of recursive function, but this just isn't working. I'm assuming because of some infinite loop occurring. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I'm curious as to what you are trying to achieve here? Could you explain what the actual problem you are trying to solve is??

Comment: "keep executing" is rather vague. Give the problem, not a guess at the solution.

Comment: Okay... The problem is I have a gallery with a bunch of images side to side. I want the gallery to slide to the right or left as long as I'm hovering on the next or previous image. `base.change( base.$panels.index($(this)) + base.adj );` lets me do this. So as long as the mouse is over one of the next panels, I want it to keep scrolling to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `mousemove` event will help you to some extent. Alternatively you can use `setInterval` on `hover` and execute the required code at a specified interval and then on `mouseout` clear the interval.

Comment: I've tried the setInterval and clearInterval method, however it still will only move one pane over.

Comment: Okay I went over my code and this did end up being the fix. Just had to slightly modify something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the mouseover event? Im not sure i understand your code exactly but below is my attempt at interpretation.

```
 $(el).mouseover(function() {

        base.change( base.$panels.index($(this)) + base.adj );
 });
```

Comment: I think the issue he is having is that he wants the base.change code to keep executing as long as the mouse is over the element and stops once it leaves.

Comment: Ah Yeah, I get that now, Mouseover will only execute once not continually so wont solve the problem in this case.